# Left join using rows with condition

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

**exp_channel_titles

exp_relationships**

I want to select distinct rows from the left table (**exp_channel_titles**) where they have a relationship defined in **exp_relationships**. I can do this with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT exp_channel_titles.title  
FROM exp_channel_titles  
LEFT JOIN exp_relationships  
ON exp_channel_titles.entry_id=exp_relationships.child_id  
WHERE exp_relationships.child_id IS NOT NULL  
AND exp_channel_titles.channel_id=5  
AND exp_channel_titles.status='open'
```

The problem is I want to make sure exp_channel_titles.status='open' for the rows used in the relationship. I'm finding this difficult to get my head around, so I'll attempt to explain better.

**exp_channel_titles** contains something like:

**entry_id | title | status | channel_id**
1 | nanny | open | 2
2 | childcare | open | 5
3 | nanny | open | 2
4 | business administration | open | 5
5 | receptionist | closed | 2

**exp_relationships** defines relationships between rows in **exp_channel_titles** using **exp_channel_titles.entry_id** as **exp_relationships.parent_id** and **exp_relationships.child_id**. So the above rows would have the following relationships:
**parent_id | child_id**
1 | 2
3 | 2
5 | 4

So the query I outlined above would give me:
childcare
business administration

But because the only entry related to business administration(receptionist) has a status of 'closed' I don't want this item to appear. I want the query to return just childcare.

Comment: What is your query returning? At first glance, it looks ok. Although, if you are requiring a relationship between the tables, you don't need to do a LEFT JOIN. You can just do a regular JOIN and get rid of the 'WHERE child_id IS NOT NULL' clause.

Comment: It returns childcare and business administration. If I do a regular JOIN and get rid of the WHERE child_id IS NOT NULL, it still doesn't apply the exp_channel_titles.status='open' to the rows used in the JOIN. i.e. I still see business administration.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example of what the exp_relationship table/data looks like?

Comment: Edited my question to show exp_relationship data. to be clear, the exp_channel_titles table contains both parent and child data.

Comment: I posted a possible solution below. You could probably also join a sub-query if you wanted as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join a table twice with aliases like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ect.title 
FROM
    exp_channel_titles ect
JOIN
    exp_relationships er
    ON ect.entry_id = er.child_id
JOIN
    exp_channel_titles ect2
    ON ect2.entry_id = er.parent_id
WHERE
    ect.channel_id = 5
    AND ect.status = 'open'
    AND ect2.status = 'open'
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this still shows entries where the related entry has a status of closed i.e. "business administration" would still show in the data set above. Will look into sub-queries, though as you may have guessed my grasp on SQL is not amazing.

Comment: Sorry, I left off a line when I copied from my sql window. I edited the above query. Maybe that'll work?